# How to disable looping inside do while loop in php?

Tags: php, loops, html-table

I used php to generate rows of html table. Here is my code:

```
<?php $cols=mysql_num_rows($grds); ?>
<tr>
  <td></td>
<?php do{  ?> 
  <td rowspan="<?php echo $cols; ?>" align="center">Internal<br />Grades</td>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;<?php echo strtoupper($row_grds['grade_name']);?></td>  
  <td align="center"><?php echo strtoupper($row_grds['igrade']);?></td>   
</tr>
<?php  } while ($row_grds=mysql_fetch_assoc($grds));?>
```

The html source generated by the above code is:

```
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td rowspan="2" align="center">Internal<br />Grades</td>
 <td colspan="2">&nbsp;RHYMES</td>  
 <td align="center">B</td>    
</tr>
 <td rowspan="2" align="center">Internal<br />Grades</td>//I don't want this.
 <td colspan="2">&nbsp;CONVERSATION</td>  
 <td align="center">A</td>    
</tr>
```

My expected output is:

```
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td rowspan="2">&nbsp;Internal<br /> Grade</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;RHYMES</td>  
<td align="center">B</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;CONVERSATION</td>  
 <td align="center">A</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Why can't you just move `<tr>` block inside the loop, and create a `rowspan` cell at the first step only?

Comment: Because my table looks bad. My question code is almost correct except that it loops the rowspan but it should not. So I tried with continue and break which worsens the looks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $i=0; while ($row_grds=mysql_fetch_assoc($grds)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
<?php if($i==0): ?>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $cols; ?>" align="center">Internal<br />Grades</td>
<?php endif; ?>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;<?php echo strtoupper($row_grds['grade_name']);?></td>  
        <td align="center"><?php echo strtoupper($row_grds['igrade']);?></td> 
    </tr>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: This is returning two rows, but it looks as if it is one row because all are spanned.

Comment: Then add <table> and </table> tags. I've assumed that you have them.

Comment: Yes, I have them. But your code returns just one row of data in a two rows which were spanned and look like one row.

Comment: Can you make jsFiddle with output to check it out? It's seems quite unlikely that it breaks down, unless you've changed something in css.

Comment: As I am using php for generating html table it is not possible to make jsFiddle, I am trying with phpfiddle. I have to simulate my data with array.

Comment: After rendering your page you can copy&paste content itself to jsfiddle.

Comment: I just solved it. I put the first row outside the loop with rowspan and put the other rows inside loop and it is working fine...thank you.